# Blender 2.80 Objects have sound attached to them?

Tags: animation, grease-pencil, audio

I want to create a simple grease pencil animation, but don't want to have to add sound later on, but would prefer for example an object to have sound attached, like a cloud rain and thunder. The sound should them be picked up by the camera, in stereo, depending on where the object is in relation to the camera, being louder or softer, left or right. So if the camera gets closer to the object, it the sound gets louder. 
I know that there was a functionality in the Blender Game Engine, which is no more as of 2.80. This is possible at all anymore?

Answer (score 1):

**Add a speaker object to your scene.**

The speaker object has just the functionality you are after.

> **[Speaker](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/audio/speaker.html)**
>
> The speaker object is used to give sound in the 3D View. After adding the object, the various settings can be changed in the
>   Properties editor.

Add a speaker to the scene ***`Add > Object > Speaker`***

Add sound and fill in the properties accordingly.

Image from 2.83

[image]

The speaker object can be animated as other objects.

Comment: This is from Blender 2.79, not from 2.80 like I asked. I have obviously found this documentation, but how do you make it ACTUALLY WORK? I get no sound and neither any info how to make it sound.

Comment: Changed link to 2.8 which since there is no great change from 2.7x is exactly the same.  Reading question again: It is not so _"obvious"_ you have found this documentation.  What have you tried?  Do you get sound after adding sound to sequencer.  What audio device are you using?

Comment: @nigratruo It should work without doing anything, maybe you are using an unsupported codec for your audio?

Comment: @melMass If you wish to communicate with OP please add commentary under question, so I don't get notified. AFAIC this answers the question as asked.

Comment: Well yes, I’m confirming your answer being the good one so it does belongs here.